# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'details'

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing

I want to use routerLink in angular app.

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
         path: 'details/:title',
        component: NewsDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let article of articles"  >
    <img src="{{article.urlToImage}}">
    <a [routerLink]="['/details',article.title]">
    <h1 (click)="goToOtherComponent()" >{{article.title}}</h1>
  </a>
    <p>{{article.description}}</p>
    <p>By <span>{{article.author}}</span></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { NewsService } from './news.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getArticles();
  }
  constructor(public service: NewsService, private router: Router) {}

  title = 'google-news';

  articles;

  // get data from service
  getArticles() {
    this.service.getNews().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.articles = data['articles'];
    });
  }
  goToOtherComponent() {
    this.router.navigate(['/details']);
  }
}
```

i tried programmatic navigation from app component to news-details component holding some data but i don't know what's wrong with my code..any help ?

Comment: Could you create stackblitz project

Comment: Is your component not render in your browser?
Is that right what i understood?

Comment: @prabhatojha i'll try to do so

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy yup now i can't see my news-details component in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@R.cs

You add `router-outlet` in your `app.component.html` based on router your component will render.
keep router-outlet in your app.component.html other that that just remove in your component.

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wfpnx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts